# Android login issue with IMC Bluegroups

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

We are getting an error while trying to login an app developed using IBM worklight.
This problem is occurring only in Android. It's working well in iPhone device.

We are using IMC blue group along with bluepage authentication. First it checks the IMC bluegroups, then, we make a call to an adapter for checking the bluepages authentication. From within the same adapter we are calling two adapters for completing the authentication.

We are clueless about this error.

> A user authenticated as anonymous has attempted to access a session
>   owned by user:bluepages.ibm.com ...

[image]

Comment: Does this happen in the development environment or in a production environment? What is the WAS version?

Comment: Hello Idan, Thanks for the reply!! Its a production environment & with WAS version 8.5.5.2

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this similar question and its answers: [SESN0008E: A user authenticated as anonymous has attempted to access a session owned by user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868734/sesn0008e-a-user-authenticated-as-anonymous-has-attempted-to-access-a-session-o)

Also review the following developer comment:

> It is normal, it can occur with every secured application (not only
>   Worklight) due to the WAS LTPA management and the browser sharing of
>   the LTPA token on the same domain. It is not possible to handle it by
>   the applications.
>
> SESN0008E is sent by the WAS security layer when you try to access an
>   existing session that is owned by another user.  The problem is that
>   if you launch in another browser tab a URL that uses the same domain
>   than a previous one the LTPA token is the same that a previous
>   session.  So for the last stackoverflow situation, the user
>   authenticates to the WL admin console with a user and then run the
>   common preview of a WL application in a a new browser tab. It uses the
>   same session but with another user (or no user) so it fails with this
>   exception.
>
> See also for example the technote :
>   http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21649895.
>
> To avoid this one solution if possible is to use seperated domains for
>   the console and the WL applications. Other one is to use another
>   browser or clear the brower cache.

Comment: Idan, We are getting this error while trying to login the app from our Android mobile devices, the code is deployed in a remote DST server, so there is no browser coming into picture ? In other thread you pointed out, how about putting the below line to server.xml ? <httpSession securityIntegrationEnabled="false"/> One more thing, I get the feeling this issue might have come after we set the credentials for the WAS console , any idea ?